# Converting Decimal to String by String(format:...) in Swift

Tags: swift, decimal

Could you help me with a following case:
When I try "eachPersonPays" to convert from Decimal to String, I got error "Argument type 'Decimal' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'".
When I confirmed to fix to "as CVarArg" I don't get "totalBill" calculated.

What should I do in line:
totalBill = String(format: "%.2", eachPersonPays)
so that I can get totalBill calculated.

```
@IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    bill = billTextField.text!
    if (Decimal(string: bill) != nil) == true {
        let eachPersonPays: Decimal = (Decimal(string: bill)! * tip) / Decimal(string: numberOfPeople)!
        totalBill = String(format: "%.2", eachPersonPays)
        print(totalBill)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
        
    } else {
        billTextField.text = "input bill amount"
```

P.S.
I hope I could explain properly what the problem I have.

Comment: Just use number formatter instead

Comment: You should use a number formatted to give users the correct format according to their local. Your particular format, as obvious or correct as it may seem from personal experience, is not what most users use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specifier of the numeric object `@` is missing: `format: "%@.2"`

By the way

```
if (Decimal(string: bill) != nil) == true
```

is horribly *unswifty*, there is [Optional Binding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330)

```
if let decimalBill = Decimal(string: bill),
   let decimalNumberOfPeople = Decimal(string: numberOfPeople) {
     let eachPersonPays = decimalBill * tip / decimalNumberOfPeople
     let totalBill = String(format: "%@.2", eachPersonPays as CVarArg) // or as NSNumber
}
```

Comment: Vadian, God bless you!

Comment: Vadian, I was too fast, unfortunately it's not working